# Force Proximity Search into multiple word wordform?

Tags: sphinx, proximity

I use Proximity to good use with Sphinx e.g. `Twain NEAR/1 Mark` will return

Mark Twain

and

Twain, Mark

But say I had a word form like:

Weekday > Week Day

How could I set any given search to use Proximity `NEAR/3` (or `NEAR/X`) so it would find

Week Day

and

Day of Week

I get in this case there are other ways to skin the cat but in general, looking for a way that the multiple word map doe not get pushed as `'Word1 Word2'` i.e. `'Week Day'` because otherwise I get docs such as

'I worked for one entire day before realizing it was going to take a

full week'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way out of the box. You can perhaps make a change in your app so it does changes each 'word' to "word"~N in your search query or even better do that only for the same wordforms that Sphinx deals with. Here's an example:

```
mysql> select *, weight() from idx_min where match('weekday');
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
| id   | doc                                                                           | a    | weight() |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
|    1 | Weekday                                                                       |    1 |     2319 |
|    2 | day of week                                                                   |    2 |     1319 |
|    3 | I worked for one entire day before realizing it was going to take a full week |    3 |     1319 |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *, weight() from idx_min where match('"weekday"');
+------+---------+------+----------+
| id   | doc     | a    | weight() |
+------+---------+------+----------+
|    1 | Weekday |    1 |     2319 |
+------+---------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *, weight() from idx_min where match('"weekday"~2');
+------+-------------+------+----------+
| id   | doc         | a    | weight() |
+------+-------------+------+----------+
|    1 | Weekday     |    1 |     2319 |
|    2 | day of week |    2 |     1319 |
+------+-------------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *, weight() from idx_min where match('"entire"~2 "day"~2');
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
| id   | doc                                                                           | a    | weight() |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
|    3 | I worked for one entire day before realizing it was going to take a full week |    3 |     1500 |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *, weight() from idx_min where match('weekday full week');
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
| id   | doc                                                                           | a    | weight() |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
|    3 | I worked for one entire day before realizing it was going to take a full week |    3 |     2439 |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select *, weight() from idx_min where match('"weekday"~2 full week');
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The last one would be the best way to go, but you would have to:

1) parse your query. E.g. like this:

```
mysql> call keywords('weekday full week', 'idx_min');
+------+-----------+------------+
| qpos | tokenized | normalized |
+------+-----------+------------+
| 1    | weekday   | week       |
| 2    | weekday   | day        |
| 3    | full      | full       |
| 4    | week      | week       |
+------+-----------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and if you see that for the same tokenized word you get 2 different normalized words that can be a signal for your app to wrap the tokenized word into "word"~N.

2) run the query. In this case "weekday"~2 full week

Comment: Very interesting. I'm assuming -2 is a shorthand for NEAR/2? And that in fact if you specify NEAR/N for a given word in a query it then pushed the mapped wordform in with the same ruleset? I can easily modify the app to do so if this is the case. Will report back...

Comment: Ok this seems to work with one caveat; wordforms are affected but any regex in the config is not.